# Indexing/Importing data from big JSON file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

Does anyone tried to add/create index to ES from JSON files.
I am looking for solution where I can "import"  lots of data from JSON files directly to ES.

So far I found two plugins.

First is [FileSystem River for Elasticsearch](http://www.pilato.fr/fsriver/). The problem with this ES plugin that either plugin uncompatible with latest versions of ES or something else. In any case I just cannot make it work.

My JSON files are valid files, so there is no problems file files.

The second plugin [Elasticdump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump). Great ES plugin for backups, restore from backups and easy transferring data to other clasters. But no-good for "import"/indexing directly from the list of files.

There is also [Bulk Api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) in ES with but it is not clear if it usable for "importing" from files.

Any thought/examples/directions on that?

Comment: I feel like I may be missing something regarding your requirements, but is there a reason you can't write your own application to read the JSON files and send the content to the index API? - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html - Note that the bulk API is only a means to perform *multiple* operations in a single call, like multiple index calls, it's mostly concerned with improving efficiency, not any distinct functionality.

Comment: I  thought that I probably not first person who have to achieve it and there are also list of plugin rivers on ES site. So I was hoping that something already exit.  Well, most likely I have write a code to accomplish it. Thank you @Snixtor

Comment: Rivers may *seem* like an easy answer for pulling data into ES, but practically their limitations are notorious for becoming problematic as things progress. Some will even make the bold statement that they are "not for Production". Once you dive into the ES API, you'll quickly find that it's friendly enough to work with that you never really needed a river.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that _AWS CloudSearch_ http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch does exactly that. Though it's a paid service, it also has a 30 day free trial.